# Quickest command to delete all characters in the buffer after current character?

Tags: vim

I frequently need to delete all the characters from the cursor to the end of the buffer.

Is there a quick way to do this? Ideally I would like to type something very quick and intuitive and similar to the other delete commands I use a lot, like "d/target" or "dt" or "df," (delete to the next "," on the line) or "d$".

Invariably, I use "dG" at first, without thinking about it. It's "intuitively obvious". But of course, that doesn't usually do what I want...sometimes it erases the entire buffer!! (I understand why, so that is not my question.)

I have tried "dvG" and "dG". I no longer expect these to work, of course.  They are "working as designed).

I guess I sometimes fumble around to first deleting to end of line, sentence, or paragraph, and then making sure I am on a new line, and then using "dG".

I am hoping there is a cleaner way.

Comment: `vG$d` should do it

Comment: ...and of course you can bind that to a shorter sequence, like `:nnoremap <leader>D vG$d` (this allows me to type `\D` to perform this action).

Comment: I appreciate all of the tips. None of them is what I was looking for--a quick easy-to remember out-of-the box sequence consistent with vim's standard behavior. But I realize now that there is no answer. It is two quirks of vim. First, "d" appears to be a delete character command, but it is actually a delete character or a delete line command, depending upon what motion you specify. There is no way to learn the logic of it, you just have to memorize the quirk and the best available workaround.  Second, there is no motion for "last character in the buffer".

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>ctrl-end</kbd>.

If you find it inconvenient to type then create a mapping for `:h mapmode-o`.